# HTML files won't display icons when hosting on server

Tags: html

so I have a website, but the icons only display if I click on my html files, but not when I host the files on my server.

http://nishki.com/

That's my website where the icons are not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the location of images and fonts provided in your html file. As the path provided are relative. When the file is served through the server the path provided donot match.
The font files as per your network request should be present at :http://nishki.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1 i.e font folder should be present parallel to server file.
Similarly the image folder should be present parallel to server file.

Comment: I wanna thank you all for your help, I was so stupid to forget to upload the images and fonts directory to my server. Thanks to all of you!